# Ubuntu 13.04 shutdown countdown

Tags: ubuntu, shutdown

I used Ubuntu from 9.04 version and find a feature quite useful, which is shutdown for 60s.

However, for 13.04, this feature is removed.

So, could I configure the system so that it can reserve this?

Thanks!

Comment: 13.04 Has yet to be released....

Answer (score 1):

If you are so keen on doing so, you can use the `shutdown` software from the terminal likewise:

```
sudo shutdown -h +1 "The computer is now shutting down."
```